# Custom dataset like container for generic lists

Tags: c#, generics, c#-4.0, c#-3.0, c#-2.0

if I want to create a custom container like dataset for placing multiple generic lists in it what can I do?

in dataset we can place some datatable with different columns and rows.is it possible for generic lists?

thanks

Comment: Could you explain your purpose in more detail?

Comment: So far sounds like a generic list of generic lists.

Comment: I have a WCF service for my reference data that returns data from multiple table in database.currently I use datatables and palce them in a dataset for get my ref data in single request and response.I want to do this using generic lists

Comment: Why this question has 2 vote for close?I bet any body that vote this question to close don't understand my perpectives

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as long as each type can be serialized to XML then you can store it in a DataSet. For each list you can add a new datatable to the dataset. You may then add whatever columns to the table you need to store your list item properties.

It would not be too difficult to use reflection to build a generic function to examine your generic list and build a table based on type being stored there. The end result would a single dataset object with 1 to many tables, each representing the contents of a generic list. You will want to remember to store, probably as an attribute of the datatable the typeName being stored.

> in dataset we can place some datatable with different columns and rows.is it possible for generic lists?

*note: your statement is a bit confusing to me, I am concerned something is lost in translation*

If what you are trying to do is create something `list<object> NimasList = new list<object>();` and then store divergent types in a single generic list, your serialization and deserialization just got more complex, but it is still achievable.

Comment: thanks but in performance point of view I don't want convert my lists to datatables(however this is a choice and possible) but I want place my lists in a container and can access them using this such (sample) syntax: myList["MyList1"] or myList.Lists["MyList1"]

Comment: if I declare a List<object> then order I place lists in it would be important.I(and my programmers( don't want to know what order Items placed